# Don't allow questions with close votes to be bountied

Tags: feature-request, bounties, vote-to-close

Since [close votes expire during the bounty's duration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120675/close-votes-shouldnt-expire-on-bountied-questions), the current solution is to [flag the post and get a mod involved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140566/172420).  Why should mods need to be involved? We don't allow questions with bounties to receive close votes. It should go both ways.

For similar reasons, [someone suggested that bounties should not be allowed on recently reopened questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180486/dont-allow-bounty-on-a-recently-reopened-question)  The answer was that:

> The questions that, usually, go through multiple, swift, close/reopen cycles are those that are currently being discussed on meta or new ones, i.e. those that are not yet eligible for a bounty.

It then went into the "flag for mod" answer.  I'm not familiar with other sites, but on Gaming, we close two day old questions all the time.  If a question slips through the cracks and doesn't get closed right away, it is usually days or even weeks before the issue is brought back up.

The "flag for mod" answer works, but it seems unnecessarily complicated.  What if a mod isn't around?  It would be much simpler to simply disallow bounties on questions with close votes.  Now that [we can take close votes back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915), we don't even have to wait if a question with close votes gets fixed.

Comment: This seems to be a symptom of a larger problem: It should be possible to close a question in less than two days, but the close queue on SO is a living breathing nightmare in desperate need of cleanup.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That happens because some questions are so uninteresting they never get the necessary views to achieve close velocity.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The problem is they don't get that first vote to end up in the queue.  Sometimes there is also disagreement about whether or not they _need_ to be closed.  In any case, a bounty just interferes with the process.

Comment: Maybe we can introduce a system where if someone flags a question as unclear (or something else) then that extends the time it takes to put a bounty on the question? (This is not an entire solution but maybe part of it)?