# Do not allow bounties to be offered if there is a close review pending

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, bounties

We have [discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142482/263383) that (and why) it is impossible to cast close votes on bountied questions, and this is not about that, but a related issue:

It is possible to post a bounty *while the post in question is currently pending review in the close review queue*.

A pending review indicates that the question is potentially off-topic, and it is not readily apparent why we should allow bounties to be posted on such questions (while it is indeed clear that closing already bountied questions brings a host of issues related to refunding the bounty with it that only moderators can deal with, as has been discussed before).

Therefore, this is a feature request to disable the ability to bounty a question if the question is currently pending review in the close queue, i.e. if there are close votes cast on it that have not been countered by the required three *leave open* votes to take it out of the queue.

---

The [second question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188916/263383) this has been closed as a duplicate of is very close to being a duplicate, but I linked the other question *in my very first sentence*. This isn't about casting votes on bountied questions, it's about bountying questions with close votes. My proposal is a bit narrower than that of the second question - "pending close review" is a weaker condition than "has close votes", but if you think that this difference is not sufficient to make a seperate feature request, so be it. (In that case, perhaps leave a comment on what I should do with this narrower proposal: Leave it as a comment on the other question? As an answer? Nothing?)

Comment: @slugster That is the opposite way around, so no dupe

Comment: @james I don't believe so - posting a bounty prevents further close votes, so while this question is phrased slightly differently its still the same problem.

Comment: @slugster A) "dont allow close votes on a question which already has a bounty" vs B) "dont allow bounty to be posted on a question with a close vote". While a similar end result *might* occur, they are different in that the two paths are very different.

Comment: @ACuriousMind And what about the first question which your question here is *also* closed as a dupe as? "Please stop bounties from turning off community moderation"